# Windows 10 Sound Mixer: Is it normal for only speakers to show activity?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, speakers

I can open a cmd.exe terminal in windows 10 and [`echo ^G`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27080437/61624) to make the terminal beep. When I do this, the Windows 10 sound mixer shows activity for my speakers (first column), but NOT anywhere else.

[image]

I would have thought this was a System Sound or maybe a Console Window Host sound, so I'm a little confused. Is it normal for the Speakers to be the only column showing activity?

It looks the same when I play a youtube video on FireFox.

(I can't find the official documentation on the sound mixer, that's what I really want. I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with my speakers, where at random times, the volume goes to full blast even though it's showing as the lowest setting.)

---

Update: some time later, the Console Window Host column disappeared from the mixer, but when I
[`echo ^G`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27080437/61624)'d, it reappeared. It still doesn't show activity, though.